# How to combine top and count in ms access sql so that every record other than the 1st is retrieved?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to combine top and count in ms access sql so that every record other than the 1st is retrieved? i.e. exclude the 1st record, but do not know the number of records that exists.

I imagine the sql would be something like:

```
SELECT TOP 

(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Company LEFT JOIN CompanySecretary ON Company.[Company Number] = CompanySecretary.[Company Number]
WHERE Company.[Company Number]=[Forms]![Company]![Company Number]
- 1)

Company.[Company Number], CompanySecretary.[Name]
FROM Company LEFT JOIN CompanySecretary ON Company.[Company Number] = CompanySecretary.[Company Number]
WHERE Company.[Company Number]=[Forms]![Company]![Company Number]
ORDER BY Company.[Company Number] ASC, CompanySecretary.[Name] ASC;
```

E.g.

```
Company.[Company Number] | CompanySecretary.[Name] 
---------------------------------------------------
                     002 | Mark 
                     002 | Paul 
                     002 | William
```

The expected result would be:

```
Company.[Company Number] | CompanySecretary.[Name] 
---------------------------------------------------
                     002 | Paul 
                     002 | William
```

Thank you so much. 
Grateful.

Comment: I guess `ASC` - not `AESC`

Comment: Off-topic: change your name to something meaningful :)

Comment: A small data sample and the expected result would help.  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Welcome aboard, Do you have to use `TOP` and `COUNT`? like an exercise in JET SQL course, or you really need the right answer whatever it is like in real life?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is for real life. I am not sure if there is any other way, but I am new to this. Would love to hear your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The question doesn't make sense for a couple of reasons.  First `AESC` is quite ambiguous -- `ASC` or `DESC`.  Second, you are ordering by the column used in the `WHERE`, so it has a constant value.  SQL result sets (and tables) have no "first" row, unless a column specifies the ordering.  If the values are all equal, then no column specifies the ordering.

Comment: You are quite right, I am oversimplifying (the original sql is way too long). Please see the corrected post - with the left joins. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no 2 secretaries in same company with same name

```
SELECT TOP 1 Company.[Company Number], CompanySecretary.[Name]
 FROM Company LEFT JOIN CompanySecretary 
              ON Company.[Company Number] = CompanySecretary.[Company Number]
 WHERE Company.[Company Number]=[Forms]![Company]![Company Number]
 ORDER BY Company.[Company Number] ASC, CompanySecretary.[Name] ASC
```

These are the pair of values to exclude from the result set

Lets create this as `qTop1` in Access queries

Now the desired query will be

```
SELECT Company.[Company Number], CompanySecretary.[Name]
 FROM Company LEFT JOIN CompanySecretary 
               ON Company.[Company Number] = CompanySecretary.[Company Number]
 WHERE Company.[Company Number]=[Forms]![Company]![Company Number]
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM qTop1 
                        WHERE qTop1.[Company Number] = Company.[Company Number]
                               AND qTop1.Name = CompanySecretary.[Name])    
 ORDER BY Company.[Company Number] ASC, CompanySecretary.[Name] ASC
```